# failed to upgrade imagemagick

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, imagemagick

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and failing to upgrade imagemagick. The following is output from `aptitude` command, which gives more information than `apt-get`.

```
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
The following packages will be upgraded:
  imagemagick-6.q16 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  imagemagick 
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/387 kB of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
(Reading database ... 543355 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../imagemagick-6.q16_8%3a6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking imagemagick-6.q16 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.6) over (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick-6.q16_8%3a6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/import' before installing new version: Invalid cross-device link
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/imagemagick-6.q16_8%3a6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

And this is the permission of the file:

```
ls -lah /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/import
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Mar 31 09:41 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/import
```

### Questions:

Why is `import` a `c` device type? And how do I upgrade `imagemagick` in this case?

Comment: Is your `/usr` on another device? or `/usr/lib`?

Comment: @Jos I have all `/usr` and  `/` on one partition.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply run updates and image magic will be updated as part of it. It's completely understandable that trying to update imagemagic alone fail if it has newer dependecies in it's new version that your current system doesn't meet.

`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

or :

[image: updates]

Comment: That does not work, therefore I tried `aptitude`.  Anyway, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart the computer in recovery mode
2. run fix broken packages with `dpkg` from the menu.
3. run `df -h` to check if partitions are mounted correctly
4. run `apt-get install imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16`.

Problem solved.